# manipulate dom with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to preface this by saying that I am a back-end developer that has really only used Javascript for form validation.

I have been given an assignment to using "Pure Javascript" to manipulate the DOM to use Semantic HTML 5 tags. I was told that the person who gave the assignment was concerned that I "used HTML knowledge instead of the requested Javascript". In looking at the javascipt code that I used, does anyone have an idea what "I used my HTML knowledge instead of the requested Javascript" might mean? I know the Javascript is inline, but that is where the page template had for me to add it.

Any comments or answers would be much appreciated.

The following is the page. I added the code that is under the "use strict" line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Animal Facts</title>
        <style>
            body{
                font-size:1.2rem;
                font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
            }
            figure img{max-width:100%;height:auto}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1>Animal Facts</h1>

            <div class="image">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="Lorem Ipsum"/>   
                <div class="caption">Placeholder Image</div>
            </div>

            <div class="animal-facts">
                <div class="description">Bear Facts</div>
                <h1>Unlike Many Mammals...</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Polar bears are the largest land predators on earth,standing over 11' high and weighing over 1,700 lbs.</li>
                    <li>The giant panda is actually a bear.</li>
                    <li>Bears have an excellent sense of smell, better than dogs or possibly any other mammal.</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="animal-facts">
                <div class="description">Tiger Facts</div>
                <h1>Interesting information about tigers</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>Tigers are the largest wild cats in the world. Adults can weigh up to 363kg – that’s about the same as ten ten year olds! – and measure up to 3.3m!</li>
                    <li>Tigers are carnivores, eating only meat. They mainly feed on large mammals such as deer, wild pigs, antelope and buffalo.</li>
                    <li>Did you know that we have a FREE downloadable tiger primary resource? Great for teachers, homeschoolers and parents alike!</li>
                    <li>Tigers are solitary hunters, and generally search for food alone at night. They quietly stalk their prey until they are close enough to pounce – then they kill their victim with a bite to the neck or back of the head. Ouch!</li>
                    <li>Unlike most members of the cat family, tigers like water. They are good swimmers and often cool off in pools or streams.</li>
                    <li>When a tiger wants to be heard, you’ll know about it, gang – because their roar can be heard as far as three kilometres away.</li>
                    <li>They may be big and heavy, but tigers are by no means slow movers. In fact, at full speed they can reach up to 65km/h!</li>
                    <li>These fierce felines have walked the earth for a long time. Fossil remains of tigers found in parts of China are believed to be 2 million years old. Yikes!</li>
                    <li>Every tiger in the world is unique – no two tigers have the same pattern of stripes.</li>
                    <li>Today, there are five subspecies of tiger: Bengal, South China, Indochinese, Sumatran and Siberian. Sadly, three subspecies of tiger have become extinct – Caspian, Bali and Javan.</li>
                    <li>Less than 100 years ago, tigers could be found throughout Asia. Sadly, hunting and habitat loss have put populations at risk, and today their range has been reduced to around 7% of its former size. That’s why we need to do all we can to protect these beautiful beasts!</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

     "use strict";

    /** Put Javascript code here **/
    /**Create variables to store current tags that will be reused after the conversion **/
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
    var ulTiger = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[1];
    var ulBear = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    var h1Tiger = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[2]
    var h1Bear = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[1];
    var h1Main = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
    var body = document.body

    /**Create variables for the new Semantic HTML5 tags that will be in the page after the conversion **/
    var Main = document.createElement('main');
    var detailsTiger = document.createElement('details');
    var detailsBear = document.createElement('details');
    var summaryTiger = document.createElement('summary');
    var summaryBear = document.createElement('summary');
    var figCaption = document.createElement('figcaption');
    var figure = document.createElement('figure');

    /**Set the first div into a variable so that the <main> can replace the  outer <div> after the conversion
       This is done so that I can create the main tag with all of its contents prior to removing the outer <div>
       from the document **/
    var child = document.getElementByTagName('div')[0];

    /**Add the text and image to the figure tag and Append the figcaption tag to it **/
    figCaption.textContent = 'Placeholder Image';
    figure.innerHTML = '<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500x300" alt="Lorem Ipsum">';
    figure.append(figCaption);

    /**Add the animal <detail> and <summary> tags in the correct order
    summaryTiger.innerText = 'Tiger Facts';
    detailsTiger.appendChild(ulTiger);

    ulTiger.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", summaryTiger);

    ulTiger.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", h1Tiger);


    summaryBear.innerText = 'Bear Facts';
    detailsBear.appendChild(ulBear);
    ulBear.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", summaryBear);

    ulBear.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", h1Bear);


    /** Insert the new <main> tag into the <body> before the outer <div>. This is done so that 
        the new Semantic HTML5 tags are created and placed prior to removing the <div> tags 
        from the document**/
    body.insertBefore(Main, div);

    /** Insert the new <details> tags and their contents into the new <main> element **/
    Main.append(detailsTiger);
    Main.insertBefore(detailsBear, detailsTiger);
    Main.insertBefore(figure, detailsBear);
    Main.insertBefore(h1Main, figure);

    /** Now that all of the new Semantic HTML5 tags have been added, we can remove the outer <div> 
        and all of its contents from the document **/
    body.removeChild(child);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what was meant by the comment, but it's typically bad practice to embed JavaScript in an inline `<script>` tag. It's better to store that in an external `.js` file and reference it via the script's `src` attribute.

Comment: "Pure JavaScript" probably means you're not allowed to use any libraries like e. g. jQuery.

Comment: _"tell me what that means"_ probably should go back to that person and ask them to clarify what they mean. Also you are already using _"pure javascript"_ as you aren't using any javascript library (ie only using native methods)

Comment: If you are able to edit the original file containing the markup, I'm very confused as to why it is a requirement to have javascript create the additional markup in the first place.

Comment: `I was told that I used my HTML knowledge` which was probably the better way. A lot of people (including myself) disable javascript by default which would make the page unusable without using a proper html base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an assignment, I believe that you should not be given the exact solution, but try to learn by looking at examples. Understand things, and experiment.

To try and help you, here is how I would do it, but not using every step described in your assignment:

```
/*
 * Replaces all DOM elements matching the given selector
 * with an element using the given tagName
 */
function replaceElements(selector, tagName) {
    // For every element matching the selector
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).forEach(function (el) {
        // Create an element with the new tagName
        var wrapper = document.createElement(tagName);
        // Insert it before the element to replace
        el.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", wrapper);
        // Transfer child nodes
        while (el.childNodes.length > 0) {
            wrapper.appendChild(el.childNodes[0]);
        }
        // Remove the old element
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    });
}

// Replace the outer div with a main element
replaceElements('body>div:first-of-type', 'main');

// Replace image figure and caption
replaceElements('.image', 'figure');
replaceElements('.caption', 'figcaption');

// Replace details and summaries
replaceElements('.description', 'summary');
replaceElements('.animal-facts h1', 'detail');
// Switch their order
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('summary')).forEach(function (summary) {
    summary.parentNode.insertBefore(summary.nextElementSibling, summary);
});
```

As others have said, using *"pure JavaScript"* means that you don't use any library such as jQuery. Of course, this is a figure of speech, since jQuery is actually nothing but pure Javascript itself.

Comment: I agree completely blex. I did not want the answer, but I am just not clear on the context of the question and hoped someone more experienced in JS might have an idea that would clear my confusion. I have done searches on pure javascript and everything looks to be what I have done. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looking at your sample, I think I have it figured out. The issue was that I was not using node relationships(axes) , but my knowledge of the HTML and going straight to those tags. Thanks again

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck